# How is orthogonality between a line and a circle most simply defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I was asked to show that if I have a generalized circle C, and two points not in C, then every circle going through these two points is orthogonal to C iff these two points are symmetric. Since I haven't come by anything yet but still have a hard time understanding the concept: is orthogonality between a line and a circle means the line halves the circle? How can one make sure it would stay this way for every generalized circle? Is that mobius? I could really use a guidance.

Comment: HINT ;Orthogonality is defined for their tangents.

Comment: I only have the circle tangents when intersecting with a line. Do I therefore look at the tangents in the  intersection points? 
And how would such an intersection represent the intersection for any pair of circles? 
Thank you so far. Unfortunately I have never come by the definition of orthogonality between a circle and a line so I am in the dark a little.

Comment: Wikipedia would be a good source . You cab see there for circle with orthogonality also see orthogonality of tangent segments  . You can get a bit good at it from Wolframalpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a partial answer. When the radii of two circles are perpendicular or radius of one circle is perpendicular to other radius or when radius of one acts as a tangent for other or vice versa then the pair of circles is said to be orthogonal. Orthogonality depends upn number of intersection points between circles.

Answer (score 1):

Try to imagine them as circles on the surface of a sphere if you want to visualize them.

Thus, the orthogonality is just treated as circles